# MVC Model Binding a list returns null object

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, model-binding

I'm having trouble getting a proper list, for the property LookupData, every time I post a form back, the modelbinder always returns null for just that property. I think I have done everything correctly since LookupData and its objects seem to be correctly indexed when viewing the results in the formcollection.

They get named as below but the model binder doesn't seem to want to build the list and bind it back to the property:

```
"[2].LookupData.[0].Description", 
"[2].LookupData.[0].Value", 
"[2].LookupData.[1].Description", 
"[2].LookupData.[1].Value" etc..
```

All I really want is to hide the whole LookupData property and get it back after I post a form back.

Reportparameter class:

```
public class ReportParameter
{

    [RequiredIf("Required", true, ErrorMessage = "*")]
    public string ParamValue { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string DefaultValue { get; set; }
    public string CustomProperty { get; set; }
    public string LookupQuery { get; set; }
    public bool Enabled { get; set; }
    public int MaxLength { get; set; }
    public bool Required { get; set; }
    public List<string> Dependence { get; set; }
    public List<ILookupData> LookupData { get; set; }
    public VariantType Type { get; set; }
    public ReportType Destinations { get; set; }
}
```

LookupData class

```
public interface ILookupData
{
    string Value { get; set; }
    string Description { get; set; }
}
```

My view:

```
@model List<ReportParameter>
@section scripts{


<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        $(".datepick").datepicker($.datepicker.regional["@ViewBag.LanguageCode"]);
    });
</script>
}

@using (Html.BeginForm("Report", "Reports", FormMethod.Post))
{
  <div id="searchpaneloptions" class="collapse in search-panel report-options">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <p class="pull-right lsf"><a class="close-options subtle" href="#">close</a></p>
            <h2 id="options">@Metadata.Txt("Report options") <small class="option-heading">@if (ViewBag.ReportLabel != null){ @ViewBag.ReportLabel } </small></h2>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        @if (!Model.IsNullOrEmpty())
        {
            <div class="col-md-4 ">
                @Html.EditorForModel()
            </div>
        }
    </div>
    <div class="clearfix space-before"></div>
  </div>
}
```

Editortemplate for the ReportParameter, the part where I use @Html.EditorFor(model => model.LookupData, "Lookups"):

```
@model ReportParameter


@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Name)
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Type)
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Title)
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.CustomProperty)
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.DefaultValue)
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Destinations)
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Enabled)
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.LookupQuery)
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.MaxLength)
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Required)
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Type)

@Html.ValidationSummary(true)

@{
    Model.Dependence = new List<string>(){"aaa","3222","123"}; //testing string list, same problem here
}

@if (!Model.Dependence.IsNullOrEmpty())
{
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Dependence,"Lookups2")//testing string list, same problem here
}


@if (Model.Required)
{
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.ParamValue, "*")
}

@if (Model.Type == VariantType.VT_Datetime || Model.Type == VariantType.VT_Date)
{
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Name, Model.Title, new { @class = "xcol-lg-4 control-label" })
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.ParamValue, new { @class = "form-control input-lg datepick" })
}
else if (Model.Name != "destinationoptions")
{
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Name, Model.Title, new { @class = "xcol-lg-4 control-label" })

    if (Model.LookupData.IsNullOrEmpty())
    {
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.ParamValue, new { @class = "form-control input-lg" })
    }
    else
    {
        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.ParamValue, Model.LookupData.ToSelectListItems(Model.ParamValue ?? Model.DefaultValue ?? ""))
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.LookupData, "Lookups")
    }
}
```

Editortemplate for the lookupdata property

```
@model List<ILookupData>

@for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++) { 

    @Html.EditorFor(m => m[i],"Lookup")

}
```

Editortemplate for the items in the lookupdata list

```
@model ILookupData

@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Description)
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Value)
```

Comment: I'd suggest not using an interface in models. At all (except for IList and other collection types). Model binder won't know how to create an instance of such object. So if you replace the ILookupData with correct implementation you should be ok.

Comment: Well now i tried changing ILookupData to the actual objecttype and it still wont bind.

Comment: Well, i have found the problem and that is that the editortemplate adds a period before the second indexer "[2].Lookup.[1].Value", where it should be "[2].Lookup[1].Value" for the modelbinder to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well i solved my problem by wrapping the list in its own class. I could not get this to work without the list being a property. And as @Jakub pointed out i had to change the objecttype to a concrete class rather than using the interface.

```
public class ReportParameterLookup
{
    public IList<DatLookupData> Lookup { get; set; }
}

public class ReportParameter
{

    [RequiredIf("Required", true, ErrorMessage = "*")]
    public string ParamValue { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string DefaultValue { get; set; }
    public string CustomProperty { get; set; }
    public string LookupQuery { get; set; }
    public bool Enabled { get; set; }
    public int MaxLength { get; set; }
    public bool Required { get; set; }
    public List<string> Dependence { get; set; }
    public ReportParameterLookup LookupData { get; set; }
    public VariantType Type { get; set; }
    public ReportType Destinations { get; set; }
}
```

This lead to the following correct naming "[2].LookupData.Lookup[1].Description"